# Bash: extracting url until comma

Tags: bash, url, unix

I have a text file with URLs and commas and numbers.  How do I simply extract the url until the first comma??

Input:

```
google.com,1,2,3,4
youtube.com,5,6,7,8
facebook.com,9,9,1,2
```

Output:

```
google.com
youtube.com
facebook.com
```

Answer (score 4):

with the command [cut](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cut):

```
cut -d, -f1 [FILE]
```

The `-d,` flag means that you want to split on commas and `-f1` means that you want the first field. e.g. taking input from a heredoc:

```
cut -d, -f1 <<EOF 
google.com,1,2,3,4
youtube.com,5,6,7,8
facebook.com,9,9,1,2
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure `bash` solution:

```
while IFS=, read -r url _ ; do 
    echo "$url"
done < text_file
```

With `awk` it would be like:

```
awk -F, '{$0=$1}1' text_file
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e "s/\([^,]*\).*/\1/g" <file>`

Simpler solution:

`sed -e "s/,.*//g" <file>`

If you need to make changes **in** the file, add the `-i` option to `sed`.